# How to submit a job with more python scripts for training to ml cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I have a project with more than one file of python code. 
I have a file for model, one for data utility, one for training the model.
I know how to submit  a model with all the code is in one file. 
How can I indicate that T have more file in my project?
Maybe something need to added in the `setup.py` file or `__init__.py`.

My directory looks like this:

```
setup.py
trainer/
  __init__.py
  task.py
  model/
     seq2seq.py
     model.py
  data_utli.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to manually create your own package, though you're welcome to if you want.

There are two important steps in getting the package to work automatically:

1. Create a proper [python package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)
2. Ensure your `setup.py` is correct.

In your case, the `model` subdirectory is causing issues. The quick fix is to move `trainer/model/*` to `trainer/`. Otherwise, you probably want to make `model` a proper sub-package by adding a (probably blank) `__init__.py` file in the `model/` subdirectory.

Next, ensure your `setup.py` file is correctly specified. A sample script is provided in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/packaging-trainer#recommended_project_structure), repeated here for convenience:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='trainer',
      version='0.1',
      include_package_data=True,
      description='blah',
      packages=find_packages()
)
```

You can verify that it worked by running:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

That will create a `dist` subdirectory with a file `trainer-0.1.tar.gz`. Extracting the contents of that file shows that all of the files were correctly included:

```
$ cd dist
$ tar -xvf trainer-0.1.tgz
$ find trainer-0.1/
trainer-0.1/
trainer-0.1/setup.py
trainer-0.1/setup.cfg
trainer-0.1/trainer
trainer-0.1/trainer/data_util.py
trainer-0.1/trainer/task.py
trainer-0.1/trainer/__init__.py
trainer-0.1/trainer/model
trainer-0.1/trainer/model/__init__.py
trainer-0.1/trainer/model/model.py
trainer-0.1/trainer/model/seq2seq.py
trainer-0.1/PKG-INFO
trainer-0.1/trainer.egg-info
trainer-0.1/trainer.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
trainer-0.1/trainer.egg-info/PKG-INFO
trainer-0.1/trainer.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
trainer-0.1/trainer.egg-info/top_level.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer in the ml cloud documentation
https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/packaging-trainer#to_use_the_gcloud_tool_to_use_an_existing_package_already_in_the_cloud